# How to regroup a list of custom objects into a map in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have following list of objects

```java
class Account {
    int id;
    String type;
    int balance;
    Customer customer;

    // getters setters
}

class Customer {
    int customerID;
}
```

```java
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
accounts.add(new Account(1, "abc", 17998210, new Customer(190)));
accounts.add(new Account(2, "hsj", 6786179, new Customer(190)));
accounts.add(new Account(4, "ioip", 246179, new Customer(191)));
accounts.add(new Account(4, "ewrew", 90179, new Customer(191)));
```

I want to transfer above to Map and key should be the customerID and values should be list of Account

```
Map<Integer, List<Account>>

Key            Value
190 -> Account(1, "abc", 17998210, 190)
       Account(2, "hsj", 6786179, 190)
191 -> Account(4, "ioip", 246179, 191)
       Account(4, "ewrew", 90179, 191)
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-).

```
Map<Integer, List<Account>> map =
    accounts.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Account::getCustomerID));
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/AXh8R8)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
accounts.add(new Account(1, "abc", 17998210, 190));
accounts.add(new Account(2, "hsj", 6786179, 190));
accounts.add(new Account(4, "ioip", 246179, 191));
accounts.add(new Account(4, "ewrew", 90179, 191));

Map<Integer, List<Account>> accountsMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Account account : accounts) {
    accountsMap.computeIfAbsent(account.customerID, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(account);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use the [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method with three parameters for clarity:

```java
Map<Integer, List<Account>> map = accounts.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // key - customerID
                e -> e.getCustomer().getCustomerID(),
                // value - List<Account>
                e -> List.of(e),
                // merge two lists
                (l1, l2) -> Stream.of(l1, l2)
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```